# Regularity of paths

Tags: differential-geometry

Is path $t\to(t^2,t^3)$ regular  and/or piecewise regular?

My understanding of regularity is that regular paths/curves derivate never vanishes $(=0)$. If I plot this curve in [wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=parametric+plot+%28t%5E2%2C+t%5E3%29&lk=4&num=1). It looks that origo is trublesome for regularity, but I think it's piecewise regular. Am I correct?

Comment: Have you found the derivative? And then checked for what values of $t$ it turns into zero vector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The curve $y^2=x^3$ has a cusp singularity at $x=y=0$ and so there can never be a regular parametrisation of the curve. The curve $y^2 = x^3$, where $y > 0$ is a smooth curve and has a regular parametrisation given by $t \mapsto (t^2,t^3)$ where $t > 0$. The same is true with $y<0$ and $t<0$.

The problem comes from the singular point at $x=y=0$, i.e. $t=0$.